# How to read from file to list in one line?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read numbers separated with spaces from file.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("save.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    list = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 1).Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToList();
}
```

When I try to run this code I get `System.FormatException` at `int.Parse(n)` with `n` beeing string containing content of the whole file. 
As long as I understand why I'm getting this exception I have no idea why `Split()` method is not working?

Comment: Putting something in "one line" is a dubious goal.  You could write your whole program in one line and it would be worse not better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an unnecessary 1 parameter in `Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 1)` which means only one element will be returned. It is also safer to use `RemoveEmptyEntries` option. You can also simplify reading from file with help of `File.ReadAllText`:

```
File.ReadAllText("path")
    .Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(n => int.Parse(n))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a 1 into the list of chars used for splitting the string, remove it an it works.

```
list = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
       .Split(new char[] { ' ' })
       .Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToList();
```

If you leave the 1 then the result of Split would be an array of just one element.
For example, if you have this input string

```
string input = "1 2 3 4 5";
string[] result = input.Split(new char[] {' '}, 1);
```

result will be an array like this

```
result.Length == 1; // true
result[0] == "1 2 3 4 5"; // true
```

Of course passing the string

```
int.Parse("1 2 3 4 5")
```

gives the error above.

Answer (score 1):

I always liked File.ReadAllLines() -- its goes back to .Net 2.0 and I don't have to write any code of my onw.